# Grace period on signal

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

When an object's property `isWorking` is set to YES an activity indicator should be displayed on screen. This code fixes that:

```
[RACObserve(object, isWorking) subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *isWorking) {
  if ([isWorking boolValue]) {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
  }
  else {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
  }
}];
```

How do you prevent the signal from firing unless a certain amount of time has passed, say 1 sec. This will prevent the activity indicator to blink.

Throttling will not do it in this case right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap the original signal to introduce the delay when isWorking is equal to YES.  Something like the following.

```
RACSignal *isWorkingSignal = [[RACObserve(object, isWorking)
        map:^id(NSNumber *isWorking) {
            if (YES == [isWorking boolValue]) {
                NSTimeInterval delayInterval = 2; // seconds
                return [[RACSignal return:isWorking] delay:delayInterval];
            } else {
                return [RACSignal return:isWorking];
            }
        }] switchToLatest];

[isWorkingSignal subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *isWorking) {
    if (YES == [isWorking boolValue]) {
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    }
    else {
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }
}];
```

Comment: You may be interested in [`-throttle:valuesPassingTest:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/7d161bbe2ccc69bde7de4055c2f404651453b883/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L59-L82), which does more-or-less the same thing.